# URL with mod_rewrite download an empty file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use `mod_rewrite` in my project, this is my `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . modules.php [L]
```

erveything is ok, for example when I enter this url everything is ok:

```
http://localhost/myproject/profile/zCdx/edit/_detail
```

but when I enter this URL the browser will download an empty file:

```
http://localhost/myproject/profile/zCdx/edit/_detail/edit/5
```

the request will not route to my `module.php` and my php file will not run !

What should I do?

Comment: How do you know that modules.php does not run?

Comment: because I just `echo 'Hello World !';` in `module.php` file, in first URL this message will show in browser and in second URL an empty file will be download.

Comment: I am confused why such a thing would happen. I would recommend logging the entire request to the second url and comparing it to the first url. I am guessing it is being sent with different headers. Why? I don't know. All url's, except the request to `localhost/` should be handled by modules.php. It might be an error document, sent with wrong headers. It might be a wrong configuration in this .htaccess, an other .htaccess or the main config file. You can check your Apache error log. I would recommend inspecting your Apache error log for anomalies.

Comment: Thanks for comment, after restart the apache my problem solved !! this is strange problem.

Comment: Did you make any changes to httpd.conf, the main config file? Restarting apache reloads that file.

Comment: Also, please post it as an answer if there are no more problems with the solution that worked for you. That way you can accept your own answer, so that this question will not float to the top of questions to be answered every time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the Apache and the problem solved !